# Input button image styling in IE9

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer-9

I'm styling a form, using an input where type=image. It renders fine in FF, but not in IE (pic below), where it adds a bevelled border. It's also showing the little icon thing over my image, although I'm guessing that's because it's a form element with no action associated, perhaps? -

[image]

styling for the input is as follows, all pretty simple:

```
    input.search-button {
        display:block;    
        float:left;
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        background:url(images/search.png) no-repeat;
}
```

I've tried adding border:0, no joy. Any ideas as to how to best tidy up the presentation?

Comment: Did you try `border-style: none;` or `border-style: solid;`?

Comment: Would it be possible to share html part of the search button too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the border, try setting `border:none;`.  For the input, I would double-check your path.  It looks like you are trying to use a background image INSTEAD of an actual image in the src attribute.

Also, try leading your image paths with a forward slash (/) which will take you all of the way to the root, and then drill down from there.

Hope this helps!

Matt

Comment: haha. yeah. that would be it - helps if the image is an image, not a background. how bout a hover state? Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  If so, then just assign the input an id and then use that id as a selector and switch its "src" attribute on the fly like this: $('#myImageInputId').attr('src','myNewUrl');

Comment: Obviously, you would need to wrap that in a jQuery mouseover event listener.

Comment: just realised too - changing the button back to type=submit allows styling via css, using background-image and :hover

Comment: That's true.  I have never user type=image personally, but thought that you must have had your reasons ;).

Answer (score 0):

I hope IE9/any can be rendered as IE8/IE7 by adding below line of meta in the head of html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

then the same css fits for every IE version